# Can I add a custom header to simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I'd like to download a remote page only when it differs from a version I have already. There's no "Last-Modified" or "Expires" (the server sends `Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate`) but there's the `ETag:` field.

So, I can send `If-None-Match:` header with last ETag value and on any error (including `304 Not Modified`) retry after a delay.

Currently I'm using `simplexml_load_file` to grab the URL, and I wonder if I can just call it in some way adding the extra header, or do I need to roll out more heavyweight solutions (curl, file_get_contents etc)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cURL` with adding custom header, then use [`simplexml_load_string`](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string) (with return content from cURL request) to get `SimpleXMLElement`object.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('If-None-Match:: XXX'));
```